String manipulation with variable in FOR /F
I have a number of directories, some of which are interesting:
>DIR /B
another_interesting_dir
one_boring_dir
one_interesting_dir
one_more_interesting_dir

From the interesting dirs, I want to extract the part before _interesting_dir. I've tried
FOR /F %d IN ('DIR /B ^| FINDSTR interesting') DO ECHO %d:~0,-17%

with this result:
another_interesting_dir:~0,-17%
one_interesting_dir:~0,-17%
one_more_interesting_dir:~0,-17%

So I tried
FOR /F %d IN ('DIR /B ^| FINDSTR interesting') DO SET a=%d & ECHO %a:~0,-17%

with this result:
one_more
one_more
one_more

How can I extract another, one and one_more? I'd prefer to do this in a single command, but a batch file would work too.

Could elaborate or point to the relevant documentation? I believe the ^ was missing, right?

The console has kind different batch escape rules. There is no a documentation in details, only articles on the internet.

@Andry if those are answers, please post them as an answer so that everyone can benefit.

In console:
FOR /F %d IN ('DIR /B ^| FINDSTR interesting') DO @SET "a=%d" & call ECHO.^%a:~0,-16^%

In script:
@echo off
setlocal
FOR /F %d IN ('DIR /B ^| FINDSTR interesting') DO SET "a=%d" & call ECHO.%%a:~0,-16%%

Details on batch escaping rules:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping
https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6031
https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php
https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

